# ActiveX replacement options

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc, activex, webassembly

I have a legacy (Written in C++/MFC/Win32, Windows only) application which can be used as an activex control. Till now, this has been used by embedding the ActiveX control inside the IE and using it. Now that MS is stopping support on IE, I am evaluating the options for this application. I have already tested with IE mode of Edge browser and it does work without any issues. But if I want to make it work with other modern browsers (such as Chrome/Firefox) what is the least disruptive way to do it without rewriting everything? Note that, I do not have any requirement to support other OS and existing features are fine. In my view I have the following options:

1. Explore WebAssemblies (But still this will be in sandboxed environment, my application needs file access for some features)
2. Explore the callbacks provided by V8 engine.

Any better options than these?

Comment: ActiveX controls are the only option that have been proven to work.